# Why is the inverse an element of the stabilisator of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$G$ operates on the set $X$. I have to prove:

> The stabilisator $G_x$ is a subgroup of $G$.

1. $G_x\neq \emptyset$, because for the neutral element $1\in G$ is $1.x = x$, therefore $1\in G_x$.
2. Let $g, h \in G_x$ be arbitrary. Then $g.x = x$ and $h.x = x$ and therefore $gh.x = g.(h.x) = g.x = x$, i.e. $gh \in G_x$.

Now I have to prove, that for arbitrary $g \in G_x$ the inverse $g^{-1}$ is also an element of $G_x$. I am stuck here, because I have no explanation why there should be a inverse element at all.
For the case $1\in G_x$ I can say, that the inverse of $1$ is $1$. But I cannot explain why an arbitrary element $g$ should have an inverse in $G_x$, except $g$ is inverse to itself.

Comment: " I have no explanation why there should be a inverse element at all" - that is easy. $G$ is a group, so every $g$ has an inverse in $G$. Note that $g$ is not an element of $G_x$, but rather an element of $G$.

Comment: $g$ has an inverse because $G$ is a group.

Comment: Right. I was just looking at the set $G_x$ and not $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $G$ defines an operation on $X,$ you know that you have 
$$g^{-1}\cdot (g\cdot x)=(g^{-1}g)\cdot x=1\cdot x=x$$ and as $g\cdot x=x$ from the hypothesis $g\in G_x,$ you get your result.